# How do I force a very specific grid zone in both object, vertex, line, face mode?

Tags: modeling, snapping, tilesize

I have enabled snapping to absolute grid position. I have this grid:

[image]

If I zoom in, the grid stays like I want:

[image]

But then I press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to switch to top camera view, the grid changes size which is not what I want:

[image]

I want my grid to always stay exactly at, let's say 100cm increments, in all modes and all cameras.

Is there a way to to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I found if I set the Scene Properties -> Units -> Unit System to "None" it now behaves like I'd expect.  So I will just need to know that I am sizing things to what I want manually.

Comment: Do you have the grid's _Subdivisions_ in the _Overlays_ set to 1? Because if you don't the top view will not behave as expected, even with _Unit System_ set to "None".